# Screen always on when my app runs on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have developed a iPad app and i want that the screen should never sleep or lock. I want the screen to be on when the app runs.

In android there is a screen and wake lock which handles the same, but i was unable to find the same for IOS.

I am guessing it will be some setting in Project or target. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

You should be able to put this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in your AppDelegate.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following in your viewDidLoad

```
//don't lock
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: should i add this in all the viewDidLoad of all the controllers? or just the one that launches on app start?

Comment: just add this in your rootViewController

Comment: ok, thanks, i have also handled cases when the app goes in UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and returns to foreground. Is it necessary to write there also? or just writing in viewDidLoad will do?

Comment: it will do the purpose for that app.
you are suppose to add this code only once.
no need to add it again in  UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and returns to foreground.

Comment: It would be good to test for the different cases you desire and modify  accordingly cause i am not much sure about the entering to foreground and background.

Comment: @ankit_rck If you think this is the correct solution then make it "This comment adds something useful to this post". It helps others

Comment: @DeepakBharati you shouldn't be telling users to choose your answer as correct they need to make there own mind up. If we were doing it that way I could sit here and say that mine should be chosen because I put it first and your answer adds nothing new to the overall context of answers - but I am not. Leave them to make there own mind up about which answer they want to choose don't force it on them.

Comment: @Popeye alright, thanks for the advice. 
i will be minding this.

Comment: @DeepakBharati it's alright it just gets annoying when users come along and put an answer that does nothing to add to the context of every other answer and goes chose me chose me. If I had put something completely wrong then yeah sit there and say chose mine but at least give a good reason why to choose it over the others.